# Uncaught ReferenceError: PDFObject is not defined

Tags: html, css, pdf, frontend, backend

With the HTML below I am trying to publish a PDF file into the webpage. The error as in this post's title is what I see when inspecting the page. The PDF file isn't published. Is this the best way to publish PDF into a webpage? I'm more interested in implementing the solution involving the PDF object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
}

/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* Sticky navbar - toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfobject/2.2.7/pdfobject.min.js" integrity="sha512-g16L6hyoieygYYZrtuzScNFXrrbJo/lj9+1AYsw+0CYYYZ6lx5J3x9Yyzsm+D37/7jMIGh0fDqdvyYkNWbuYuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>PDFObject.embed("C:\Users\pramo\Desktop\Work\PwP\MiiR_Impact_Report_2020.pdf", "#example1");</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <p>A <b>responsive</b> website created by me.</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="right">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</div>
<div id="example1"> 
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to know what a random library is? What is PDFObject? My guess `<script src="pdfobject.min.js"></script>` is not linking to the JS file correctly.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I followed a tutorial at https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/pdfobject-embedded-pdf-viewer-using-html5/. I'm not sure where do I get pdfobject.min.js from and my PC doesn't have it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a mock version of what you are trying to do and it works just fine. Although the sample PDF I have linked will not appear in an SO snippet because `because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.` If you open it in a live or local server or have another PDF to which you can use, then it will work fine.

I would check the relative path to your PDFObject script because it seems like it is not getting read in to your HTML as a plugin, meaning the path is incorrect. You can always use the CDN which is a direct link to the plugin/script here:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfobject/2.2.7/pdfobject.min.js" integrity="sha512-g16L6hyoieygYYZrtuzScNFXrrbJo/lj9+1AYsw+0CYYYZ6lx5J3x9Yyzsm+D37/7jMIGh0fDqdvyYkNWbuYuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Here is what it looks like when I run this code in my local server:

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*Center the PDF Object and Center Align  */

.pdfobject-container {
  width: 840px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
}

/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* Sticky navbar - toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>My Website</h1>
            <p>A <b>responsive</b> website created by me.</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="right">Link</a>
          </div>
          
          <div class="main">
              <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
              <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="example1"> 
          </div>
          
          <div class="footer">
            <h2>Footer</h2>
          </div>  

    </body>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfobject/2.2.7/pdfobject.min.js" integrity="sha512-g16L6hyoieygYYZrtuzScNFXrrbJo/lj9+1AYsw+0CYYYZ6lx5J3x9Yyzsm+D37/7jMIGh0fDqdvyYkNWbuYuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
    
     PDFObject.embed("https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf", "#example1");   
    </script>
</html>
```

Lastly, for good practice try to load your scripts right before the closing of your `</body>` tag, that way the HTML DOM can load before the JS loads.

Comment: The solution helped me save a lot of time struggling to fix it. It works, thanks.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Can you tell me what causes the src value to be <embed src="C:UserspramoDesktopWorkPwPMiiR_Impact_Report_2020.pdf" class="pdfobject" type="application/pdf" title="Embedded PDF" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;"> ? In the HTML it is correct with backslashes.

Comment: IT doesn't like the `\` backslash. If the PDF is in the same src file as your html file. You can just do `MiiR_Impact_Report_2020.pdf`.

Comment: I just copied over the PDF to where the html is, thanks.

Comment: A last question: could you please share the CSS to set its width to 840px and center align it? `.pdfobject-container { height: 500px; width: 840px; align-items: center;}` isn't working.

Comment: I want it to look like the PDF embedded in this page https://www.miir.com/pages/impact-report-2020

Comment: Please see my most recent edit, I added the following CSS: `.pdfobject-container {
  width: 840px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}`

Comment: Perfect, it worked. thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238888/discussion-between-pktg-and-beerusdev).